# How do I keep passing the output of a Halide pipeline back into the pipeline until some condition is met?

Tags: c++, image-processing, halide

I have a Halide pipeline which takes in an image, and applies some filters to it. It works fine for a single pass. I pass in an image, and I get the processed image as the output. What I would like to do is implement multiple passes i.e., I want to keep passing the output image back into the pipeline for a number of steps until some condition on the image is met.
How do I do this Halide? The only other way I could think of doing it was having an external C++ method that can invoke the pipeline in a loop. I was hoping if this is possible natively in Halide.

The code looks something like this. I want to consume output as input in a loop until some condition is met.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Buffer<uint8_t> input = Tools::load_and_convert_image("img.png");
  int W = input.width();
  int H = input.height();
  Buffer<uint8_t> output(W, H);
  // after some Funcs. res is last Func of the pipeline
  res.realize(output);
  Tools::convert_and_save_image(output, "out.png");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the pipeline a static number of times, by unrolling it into a larger pipeline. If what you are computing is expressible as a single stage, you can run it a dynamic but unconditional number of times by using an `RDom` to iterate over successive applications. However, you can not express any loops with a dynamic termination condition (what you might think of as a `while` loop). That you have to do in the calling C++ code.

You've hit on quite an insightful question. This is a conscious constraint of the language: it's the difference between loop bounds being [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)), and becoming [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). Future version of the language may extend this in targeted ways, but it's currently quite fundamental to how the compiler can infer all the bounds in your program.